# Connecting EditText to WebServices

Tags: java, android, web-services

Is it s possible to write something on a EditText and then on another activity search the PAT on the system of the company and show the information of the same one?

Example:   ActivityA - writing on a editText search for the Process number(23456)
           ActivityB - show the information of the client, like name, number, email etc ...

Comment: be more clear about the question..!!

Comment: already edited........................

Comment: **Yes possible..!!**

Comment: @user6505433 sorry I still cannot get it, what do you real want
In ActivityA use input some text? then In ActivityB you want to show something related the text in ActivityA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this If you want to search some information by **Process number** and in your search activity's Edittext you are taking it as input then,

First of all take the value out of that edittext after user typed it as under, you can do this on click event of any button,

```
String s = yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

Then you can pass this value to the next activity by putting it in `Intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("processNo",s);
```

And then in second Activity's (Ex, `OtherActivity`), in it's `onCreate()` method you can get this value by this,

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String processNo= i.getExtra("processNo"); //please be careful that you passed same key as your first activity
```

Then you can search other information related to client by this client number.you can pass this same client number in your webservice.